# How to implement two different blocs in one bloc in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

For example i have two blocs, `Bloc A` and `Bloc B`. Both `Bloc's` is calling different api's and when i open the screen or app `Bloc A` And `Bloc B` calls the api. Problem is sometimes `Bloc A` or `Bloc B` takes sometime to load so during this i display `circular progress indicator`. But it doesn't look good that is `Bloc A` builds successfully and displays the content and `Bloc B` still showing `circular progress indicator`. So how can i implement that is if both `Bloc A & B` successfully loads then display both content otherwise show only single `circular progress indicator` at the `center`. How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

My way to go would be: Create additional getter in `BlocA` and `BlocB`, like `BlocAStatus`.
Then simply create a `BlocListener` on wheter `BlocA` or `BlocB` and display content only if Bloc itself is ready and the other Bloc either.

```
BlocBuilder<BlocA, BlocAState>(
   builder: (context, state) {
    if(state.blocBStatus == BlocStatus.ready) {
      // display content
    }
   }
)
```

In order to properly communicate between BLoCs, reading `Bloc-to-Bloc Communication` documentation section should be helpful.
https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture?id=bloc-to-bloc-communication